# calculate total outside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to calculate total outise `ng-repeat` which is dependent on `ng-change` inside `ng-repeat`.

My table looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Total - total is {{tot}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="obj in Array">
         <td>
            <input ng-change="getValue(obj.Cost);" ng-model="obj.Quantity" type="number">
         </td>
        <td>
            <span ng-model="obj.ListPrice">{{obj.ListPrice}}</span>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <input type="number" ng-value="obj.Cost = obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i am calculating total

```
var total = 0;
$scope.getValue = function(Cost){
    total += parseInt(Cost);
    $scope.tot = total
}
```

which is not happening. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: sir i think you need to use angular.forEach(Array, function(item, index){total+=parseInt(item.Cost);});$scope.tot=total; this line of code inside the getValue function. and one more thing i thing you need some change in <input type="number" ng-value="obj.Cost = obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice"> and no need to call ng-change="getValue(obj.Cost);"

Comment: i have a solution if you have any trouble please knock me

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code that I can see at a glace.

**First**

```
<span ng-model="obj.ListPrice">{{obj.ListPrice}}</span>
```

You're using `ng-model` on a span which is a no go. You can read about it from the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

**Second**

```
<input type="number" ng-value="obj.Cost = obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice">
```

You're assigning the operation of assigning a value to `obj.Cost`to `ng-value`. I can only hope you understood that, I'm not sure if a better way to describe this.

I believe what you're trying to achieve is this

```
<input type="number" 
       ng-init="obj.Cost = obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice" 
       ng-value="obj.Cost" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because before it could calculate `obj.Cost`, `ng-change` gets triggered and you get the stale/old value of `Cost`. So, instead, you could do something like this:

```
$scope.getValue = function() {
  $scope.total = 0
  $scope.myArray.forEach(function(arr) {
    $scope.total += arr.Quantity * arr.ListPrice
  })
}
```

And your `input` would be:

```
<td>
  <input ng-change="getValue()" ng-model="obj.Quantity" type="number">
</td>
```

Here's the working code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myArray = [{
    Quantity: "",
    ListPrice: 100
  }, {
    Quantity: "",
    ListPrice: 200
  }]

  var total = 0;
  $scope.getValue = function(obj) {
    $scope.total = 0
    $scope.myArray.forEach(function(arr) {
      $scope.total += arr.Quantity * arr.ListPrice
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Total - total is {{total}}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="obj in myArray">
        <td>
          <input ng-change="getValue(obj);" ng-model="obj.Quantity" type="number">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span ng-model="obj.ListPrice">{{obj.ListPrice}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" ng-value="obj.Cost = obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I was doing $scope.total += arr.cost which is created later. cheers..

Answer (score 0):

You can access the total outside `ng-repeat` like this

```
<span>Total is - {{total}}</span>    
<table>
    <tbody ng-init="total = 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in Array">
         <td>
            <input ng-change="getValue(obj.Cost);" ng-model="obj.Quantity" type="number">
         </td>
        <td>
            <span ng-model="obj.ListPrice">{{obj.ListPrice}}</span>
        </td>
        <td ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + (obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice)"> 
            <input type="number" ng-value="obj.Cost = obj.Quantity * obj.ListPrice">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically you are doing sum inside `ng-repeat` and doing `ng-init` in `tbody`, so that u can access the `total` outside `ng-repeat`